# How to make logged in user as global user in magento multi-site?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, multisite

I have a single magento installation with 3 domains(websites) pointing to single magento.

https://www.aaaa.com/

https://www.bbbb.com/

https://www.cccc.com/

In the back-end 
system > configuration > customer configuration > share customer account > global

I have set the "***share customer account***" as **global** 
I am still not being able to share any logged in user on my websites
i.e. if I log in as customer from one site(https://www.aaaa.com/) and then visit the second site(https://www.bbbb.com/)
I have to re-login into the second site
even when I use SID in the url of the second site

**Question:** Is there any way to set the user globally logged in to both sites? Or am I missing anything?
Note: We use cloudflare ssl.